# Counting isomorphic cyclic shifts in a string

Tags: java, algorithm, scala

I am trying to solve an algorithmic problem for which I have a `O(n²)` time, `O(n)` memory solution (see below) instead of a `O(n)` time and memory solution.

The problem is to count the number of *isomorphic cyclic shifts* for a given string s. A *cyclic shift* is a transformation of the initial string such as if `0 <= k < n` (where n is the length of the string) :

```
cyclicShift(0) = s
cyclicShift(k) = s[k-1]...s[n-1]s[0]...s[k] if k > 0
```

A cyclic shift is said *isomorphic* if it is equal to the initial string. I have the feeling that a string can have such cycling shift iff it consists in the repetition of a pattern, but I cannot prove it. If it was the case, the problem would then become to find this pattern and then deduce the number of isomorphic cyclic shift, basing on the length of the pattern and the length of the string.

My current solution constructs all the cyclic shifts and compare them to the initial string, which is a `O(n)` operation in a loop bounded by n, leading to a complexity of `O(n²)`. Here is my code in Java for reference :

```
public int solution(String S) {
    int count = 1;
    int n     = S.length();

    // We represent the string as a LinkedList to construct the next cyclic shift
    // from a given one with a O(1) time complexity
    List<Character> list = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i=0 ; i<n ; i++) 
        list.add(S.charAt(i));

    Deque<Character> tmp = new LinkedList<>(list);
    for (int k=1 ; k<n ; k++) {
        tmp.addFirst(tmp.removeLast());
        // this test is O(n) so this solution is O(n^2)
        if (tmp.equals(list))
            count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Do you have any idea of how I could solve this problem respecting the `O(n)` requirement ? Answers can be in Java, Scala, or pseudo-code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are quite right in that an isomorphic cyclic shift means that the string consists of a repeating pattern.

Consider the first k characters of the original string, by definition of the cyclic shift they are equal to the second k characters of the original string.

Now, consider the second k characters of the original string.  These will be equal to the third k characters of the original string, and so on until you have shown that the string consists of a pattern of k characters that repeats n/k times.

Now the problem is to identify the string as a repeating pattern in O(n).

One way of doing this is to use the [KMP failure function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm#.22Partial_match.22_table_.28also_known_as_.22failure_function.22.29).  The failure function tells you the longest proper prefix of a string that matches at position i.  If you compute the value of the failure function at the end of the string it will tell you a number T which is the length of a proper prefix that matches the suffix of the string.

For example, consider the string ABCABCABC.  The failure function will be:

```
-1 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

So the value at the end of the string is 6, and this tells us that the repeating pattern is of length p=n-T, in this case 9-6=3.

Once you have this length of the smallest repeating pattern, you can simply try all multiples and check that they divide the length of the string:

```
m=p
count=0
while(m<n)
   if n%m==0: count+=1
   m+=p
```

Overall this is O(n) in time and space.

Comment: The explanation and the related link are a bit complicated for me, let me some time to study it ! Thanks for your detailed anwser

Comment: Sorry, there is probably a much simpler way of solving this problem - this is just one way that is really easy if you have a KMP function already written.

Comment: Well, I still don't really get it, but it works. That problem was definitely too hard for me to answer in time.

Comment: You can also use the Z algorithm here instead of KMP

Answer (score 0):

I recently came accross a similar problem again, the only difference being that this time the fact that the string was made of a repeated pattern was explicitly specified instead of just deducible from the specification.

I implemented easily a Python function that finds the length of the smallest repeating pattern in the string. I add it here because if is far simpler that using KMP like suggested by Peter de Rivaz, however his answer also brings a proof that the existence of an isomorphic cyclic shift implies that the string is made of a repeated pattern and also the way to solve the problem once the smallest pattern was found.

Even if it is written in Python, I believe this code is fairly easy to understand :

```
def smallestPattern(s)
    (count,res) = (0,1)
    for i,ch in enumerate(s):
        if ch != line[count]:
            count = 0
            res  += 1
        else:
            count += 1
    return res
```

Comment: I am not sure this method will always work, e.g. for 00110 00110 it should detect a repeating pattern of size 5.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz that was such a long time ago, I can't even remember what `line` was. I have to find this piece of code in its broader context

Comment: I am interested because this bit of code is much simpler than my method and I have a similar problem to solve at the moment.  I really liked the look of your approach as it looked like it might be easier to adapt than the KMP function but when I tried it out I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: I found the problem it was solving (https://www.codeeval.com/browse/107/) as well as the full code (https://github.com/Dicee/algorithmicProblems/blob/6f6611feead3ea248f6575310c796314f2c9ac84/codeeval/easy/ShortestRepetition/main.py). Now I can think about it when I have time

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz the code is bugged, it does not handle all edge cases. I can see the idea I had at the time. I'll try to make it work.

Comment: I think I get your idea now: you are searching for the first repeat of the pattern.  This is a good idea and means you can solve in O(n).  In fact, in Python you can do: "return (line+line).find(line,1)"

Comment: I tried to fix this naive logic and it made it handle more edge cases but there are still errors. The thing is that you can't just reset `count` to 0 on every mismatch. For example with your test case `00110 00110` we're going to find a mismatch on the fifth zero and we will reset `count` to 0. However, we should reset to 1 because `line[0] == line[4]`. In short, when a mismatch occurs at index `i` we should find the largest `j` such that `line[:j]` == `line[i - j: j]` and that's the index we should reset `count` to. I implemented this but it does not cover  all cases