# How can I check for a pattern in a string in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, string, algorithm, pattern-matching

If I have a string like `abcabcabc` and here, clearly, `abc` is a pattern. I want to find out patterns using c/c++.

I don't want the implementation. A pseudo-code/algorithm will do just fine.

How can I do it?

Comment: Is the string guarunteed to have a pattern? Is it of finite length?

Comment: If the string definitely consists of a repeating pattern, you can find the pattern using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26439403/counting-isomorphic-cyclic-shifts-in-a-string/26439646#26439646

Comment: For more general pattern finding algorithms, see [Data Compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression).

Answer (score 1):

Use **floyd cycle finding algorithm**. This uses slow-fast analogy to find cycle. Python source code given from Wikipedia:

```
def floyd(f, x0):
    # Main phase of algorithm: finding a repetition x_i = x_2i
    # The hare moves twice as quickly as the tortoise and
    # the distance between them increases by 1 at each step.
    # Eventually they will both be inside the cycle and then,
    # at some point, the distance between them will be
    # divisible by the period λ.
    tortoise = f(x0) # f(x0) is the element/node next to x0.
    hare = f(f(x0))
    while tortoise != hare:
        tortoise = f(tortoise)
        hare = f(f(hare))

    # At this point the tortoise position, ν, which is also equal
    # to the distance between hare and tortoise, is divisible by
    # the period λ. So hare moving in circle one step at a time, 
    # and tortoise (reset to x0) moving towards the circle, will 
    # intersect at the beginning of the circle. Because the 
    # distance between them is constant at 2ν, a multiple of λ,
    # they will agree as soon as the tortoise reaches index μ.

    # Find the position μ of first repetition.    
    mu = 0
    tortoise = x0
    while tortoise != hare:
        tortoise = f(tortoise)
        hare = f(hare)   # Hare and tortoise move at same speed
        mu += 1

    # Find the length of the shortest cycle starting from x_μ
    # The hare moves one step at a time while tortoise is still.
    # lam is incremented until λ is found.
    lam = 1
    hare = f(tortoise)
    while tortoise != hare:
        hare = f(hare)
        lam += 1

    return lam, mu
```

Time complexity of this solution is `O(λ, μ)` and auxiliary space is `O(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking up this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection 
Don't think of it as a string, but rather finding a period. Whether or not it is a string does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

One way to find out a pattern withn itself is using [Knuth-Morris-Pratt's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm)'s precomputation algorithm with a time complexity of O(P.length) where P is a given string, which computes a lookup table **'PI'** that holds the lengths of the longest suffix that matches its corresponding prefix ("a", "ab", "abc", ...).

[image]

Pseudocode taken from *Introduction to Algorithms, CLRS.* Also, 
Linux has a decent [implementation](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/ts_kmp.c)  of the above algorithm.

Therefore, *P.length -  PI[P.length]* = k = length of the smallest repeating pattern. Remember, k will always remain in the range [0, P.length).

For eg, **"abcabcabc"** = PI[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]. Here, the length of the smallest repeating pattern would be 9 - 6 = 3. But does k divide the string equally?

Hence, if P.length mod k == 0 ? P[ 1..k ] would be your repeating pattern.