# How can write my code so that it does not exceed the time limit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I was solving this problem: [Cyclic shift](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/codemonk/) and I managed to solve the problem and write the code however with one flaw. My code seems to be exceeding the time limit of the test cases. This is my code:

```
def cycle(s, n):
return s[-n:] + s[:-n]
t = int(input())
for x in range(t):
    n,k = map(int,input().split())
    hello = input()
    count = 0
    for y in range(k):
        hello2 = hello
        for z in range(len(hello)):
            shifted = cycle(hello2, 1)
            hello2 = shifted
            if shifted == hello:
               shifted = cycle(hello2, 1)
               hello = shifted
               break
            count += 1
    print(count+1)
```

How can I write this in a way where it would not exceed the time limit of the test cases? I would also appreciate it if you can explain your code in your answer(even 1-2 sentences will be fine) so that I can understand and learn what you did and how the code is working. Thanks!

EDIT:

Description of the problem: [image]

[image]

Comment: What is the time limit, and how slow is your code?

Comment: @Haveaniceday the time limit for the problem is: "Time Limit: 1.0 sec(s) for each input file" and my code takes 5.01 seconds as shown in the results.

Comment: Can you link to CodeMonk's actual page on cyclic shift, rather than just generally to CodeMonk?

Comment: Right off the bat, calling `cycle` is significantly slower than simply executing the body. Inlining will speed things up greatly if you are making a lot of calls to `cycle.`

Comment: @jjramsey that's the URL when I access the problem. Sorry, I don't think I can do anything about that, that's why I mentioned the name of the problem in my question.

Comment: Then can you at least provide a description of the problem independently of your solution?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you are inputting things with `input()`. IIRC, when I've fooled around with LeetCode, the inputs were arguments to a class method. Are you sure that you're accessing the test inputs correctly?

Comment: @chepner I added the description of the problem. Also, tried what you suggested. Same results: exceeds the time limit

Comment: @jjramsey I'm confident I'm accessing the test inputs correctly. I could be wrong but I'm pretty confident it's correct.

Comment: `s[-n:] + s[:-n]` is also expensive, because each slice creates a new copy of (part of) your string, and then the `+` creates a new string as well. Trying thinking of a way to represent a cyclic shift (possibly using extra memory) that doesn't require making so many copies.

Comment: The code doesn't seem right. Your end condition for shifts occurs when shifted string is equal to the original. However, the end condition should occur when the shifted string is equal to the maximum; if the original is not equal to the maximum it won't work.

Comment: Are you looking for help making your specific approach faster, or do you want a new way of thinking about the problem. Note, it is VERY common for code tests like this to temp people into using multiple nested loops and that is typically not the right way to approach a problem (if possible). I can give you a pseduo-code that shows how I would approach the problem, but I am not sure you want that. I also worry that if an answer appears on SO then does that poison the question for future takers?  I'm not sure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting isomorphic cyclic shifts in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26439403/counting-isomorphic-cyclic-shifts-in-a-string)

Comment: @Paul this helped me solve my problem. Thanks!